# Как добавить новые публичные своиства класса в конструкторе?

Tags: java

Есть класс, в конструкторе он получает необходимую информацию (массив строк с именами и массив с типами будущих свойств), и там-же должен создать новые свойства класса. Надеюсь понятно изъяснился. Пытаюсь написать что-то типа ActiveRecord на java.

Comment: Думаю, Вы выбрали неподходящий язык для динамического программирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы хотите, подходит для JavaScript, но не к языку Java, это против ее философии. Если есть необходимость хранить много разнотипных данных, но сделать одинаковый механизм работы с ними, то можно сделать так:

```
class PropertyContainer
{
    private final Map < String, Object > properties = new HashMap < String, Object > () ;

    public void add ( final String name, final Object value )
    {
        properties.put ( name, value ) ;
    }

    public Object get ( final String name )
    {
        return properties.get ( name ) ;
    }

    public Object remove ( final String name )
    {
        return properties.remove ( name ) ;
    }
}
```

Как видите, здесь и придумывать ничего не надо, hashmap уже предоставляет аналогичный функционал. Если все же есть необходимость использования именно класса с такими же полями, то его можно сгенерировать на лету.

```
// здесь х - уникальный сгенерированый id, 
// - для того чтоб имя класса не конфликтовало с уже существующими
class GeneratedEntity[x]
{
    // код который нужно будет сгенерировать для каждого поля
    private [Type] [Name.toLowercase()];
    public [Type]  get[Name] ()
    {
        return [name];
    }
    public void set[Name] ([Type] [Name.toLowercase()])
    {
        this.[Name.toLowercase()] = [Name.toLowercase()]
    }
}
```

где:

- Name - имя поля,
- Type - тип поля

После чего придется скомпилировать этот класс и загрузить.